# Self expire content in pen drive which can't be copied

Tags: windows, mac, file-transfer, expired-key

My friend has been working on few lectures and study material from past few years and now he want to sell his content. He is worried about his content being stolen or being used without purchase. Most of his customers are regional person to whom he will give the content manually. He as following requirement -

1. User won't be able to copy paste content (Video lectures and documents) to their PC.
2. Only 1 person can use it on one PC.
3. Content should self expire in 1 year.

Is there any way I can suggest him? I don't want his hard work go in vain. I can understand that this requirement is quite difficult to achieve but I would appreciate any suggestion which can assist him.

Comment: Your question is similar to this one https://superuser.com/questions/869838/drm-a-custom-video but with additional requirements. IMO, not doable.

Comment: [Another similar question](https://superuser.com/q/625971/432690)

Comment: The best option would be to create a website with video streaming that can't be downloaded and restricted access (username/password). Even that can be easily bypassed by advanced users but should be enough as a deterrent for regular folks.

Comment: The way to go is to make it an online course, or something of the sort

Comment: It is impossible. Unless you go for some kind of DRM copy protection, which means that you have a viewer with some kind of verification, it is going to be impossible to prevent. This is the same problem game developers face, and even their games copy protection get cracked eventually. Not doable. Even if you use an online source, it can still be downloaded and spread that way if one really wants.

Comment: The only possible way to make this work is to use psychology. Make it so that the content becomes very valuable to them and have the option to take that away and make sure every person who gets this content knows this. This means you will have to use a webserver and only online access through a username and password with logging. The user also must pay a substantial amount of money for the content. This will ensure that they do not want to crack it because that means they just thrown away a big sum of money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't prevent users from copying files from a USB drive the best you can do is make them useless to them.

To that end:

1. Each file is encrypted with a different key and different per USB stick.
2. Obviously 2048 bit encryption and etc
3. Software provided that phones home to a server to check whether the user is still eligible for access to the content.  Username and password required of course.

You will have to have a custom viewer that has access to said decryption keys which you will have to use and immediately destroy.  Fetching new copies from the server each time a file is required. When the keys is in RAM the RAM its in has 2 levels of encryption so even if the RAM is dumped its meaningless.  Obviously change the random decryption keys of the RAM every 5 minutes for added difficulty.

This is a **lot** of work to implement.

Even then a persistent hacker might be able to man-in-the-middle and get decryption keys.  If a breach is detected you can void the decryption keys.  A hacker could use screen recording software, or etc to re-record the material and OCR on the text.

However, you have dramatically raised the difficult for both you and the hacker.